# html code executing differently in chrome and safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

i am working on a project. my code is working differently in chrome and safari.
here is my code
`HTML:

```
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <ul class="rig">
<li>
        <a href="special offers.html"/><img src="gift.png" />
    <h3>Image Title</h3>

</li>
<li>
    <img src="food.png" />
    <h3>Image Title</h3>

</li>
<li>
    <img src="drink.png" />
    <h3>Image Title</h3>

</li>
<li>
    <img src="shopping.png" />
    <h3>Image Title</h3>

</li>
<li>
    <img src="events.png" />
    <h3>Image Title</h3>

</li>
<li>
    <img src="payingguest.png" />
    <h3>Image Title</h3>

</li>
</ul>
    </div>
</body>

MY CSS code:

 *{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
   body{
          width: 100%;
          margin: auto;}
   .container{
          width: 960px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          }

    ul.rig {padding-top: 100px;
           list-style: none;
           font-size: 0px;
            margin-left: -2.5%; 
            }
   ul.rig li {
            display: inline-block;
           padding: 10px;
          margin: 0 0 2.5% 2.5%;
          background: #fff;
          border: 1px solid #ddd;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-size: 1rem;
          vertical-align: top;
          box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ddd;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
          text-decoration: none;}

     ul.rig li img {
      width: 280px;
       height: 280px;
      margin: 0 0 5px; }

     ul.rig li h3 {
      margin: 5px 0 5px;
       text-decoration: none; }

     ul.rig li p {
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #999;}

     ul.rig.columns-3 li {
      width: 30.83%; }


    @media (max-width: 480px) {
       ul.grid-nav li {
       display: block;
       margin: 0 0 5px;}

    ul.grid-nav li a {
    display: block;}

    ul.rig {
    margin-left: 0; }

    ul.rig li {
    width: 100% !important; 
    margin: 0 0 20px;}
    }
```

my problem is i executed same code in safari, chrome, internet explorer. its working fine chrome and internet explorer. but in safari it not.

the code is about displaying images in grid. this code displays 3 images in a row. but in safari its displaying only 2 images in a row.

i really appreciate your help.

Comment: Browsers have default styles, this will probably be the cause. You can include a reset CSS page (pre-made, look around the web) and it resets all browsers default styles.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i already tried it. result is still same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your margin on the `ul.rig li` elements. You have it with a left margin of 2.5%. Chrome, IE, etc are rounding the pixels down so your 3 elements fit and Safari is rounding up so that only 2 fit. Since your container is a fixed width, try giving fixed margins rather than a percentage. Either that or you could increase the container size slightly or reduce your margin to `margin: 0 0 2.5% 2.4%;` http://jsfiddle.net/354rxymj/1/